# Writing DataFrame rows to different database Tables using re.match and SQLite

Tags: python, regex, database, sqlite, dataframe

**RESOLVED - SEE FINAL EDIT AT BOTTOM.**

I have a DataFrame that looks the following way:

```
df_transpose=
Time                     Date  Morning (5AM-9AM)  Day (9AM-6PM)  \
Area                                                            
D1_NY_1         01_05_2012           0.000000       0.000000   
D2_NY_2         01_05_2012           0.000000       0.000000   
D3_NJ_1         01_05_2012           1.000000       0.966667
   ...
```

I want to write this row-by-row to different tables in a database using SQLite. I've set up the database `Data.db` which contains separate tables for each Area - i.e. the table names contain the Area names as listed in the DataFrame above (ex "Table_D1-NY-1" ect.). I want to test if theres a match between the Area (the index) in the DataFrame above and the names of the tables in my database, and if there's a match write the entire relevant row of the DataFrame to the Table that contains the same Area in the name. Here is what I've written so far, as well as the error I get:

**CODE:**

```
    ii=0
    for ii in range(0,row_count):
        df_area= df_transpose.index[ii]
        export_data= df_transpose.iloc[ii]
        cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
        available_tables=(cur.fetchall())
        for iii in range (0, row_count):
            if re.match('\w*'+df_area, available_tables[iii]):
                relevant_table=available_tables[iii]
                export_data.to_sql(name=relevant_table, con=con, if_exists=append)
            iii=iii+1
```

**ERROR:** for the "if re.match..." line:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I tried to make the second (iii)loop after searching for solutions to the problem to avoid inputting a list object (`available_tables`) (instead of a string) to re.match(). I still get the same error though. Can anyone see my error or help me fix my the code?

**EDIT:**
For information, `df_area` and `available_tables` outputs the following:

```
df_area=
u'D1_NY_1

available_tables=
[(u'US_D1_NY_1',), (u'US_D2_NY_2',), (u'US_D3_NJ_1',), ...]
```

**EDIT:**

Have not been able to figure this out yet and would appreciate input. I've tried to play around with my code but the error remains the same.

**FINAL EDIT:**
Thought I would post how I got past this. The problem was that before `available_tables` was a **list of tuples**, instead of a list of strings. To get the re.match() test to work `available_tables` had to be a list of strings. I changed this using the following command:

```
        cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
        available_tables=[item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, but maybe try `r'\w*'` instead of `'\w'` since you're using a backslash.

Also, it seems from the output you gave that `available_tables` is a list of tuples. So you'd probably want to use:

```
re.match(r'\w*'+df_area, available_tables[iii][0])
```